# check if url can be loaded in an iframe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iframe

Snip.ly nicely checks if the entered web address can be used in an iframe.
I'd like to replicate it in ruby. Looking through their code they send an ajax request to their server and thats where they do the validation.

Even after extensive googling couldn't find anything that could help me accomplish that.

My use case is that we let users add news listings to their page, which are shown in iframes, and would like to show it if the entered url can be used in an iframe.

Comment: what if the page includes a JS code that determines if it is inside an iframe and depending on the result, to fire a AJAX request to the server ?

Comment: @yeyo i didn't quite get what you meant

Comment: Many things like Adblock, firewall etc. can block loading an url. I think the best you can do on the backend is sending a request to the requested url, check if there is any response, and check the `X-Frame-Options` response header. It can block loading the response into an iframe.

Comment: tried that, doesn't work for all all pages

Answer (score 0):

You can figure out some cases by checking the `X-Frame-Options` header. But as you mentioned in the comments, it does not work all the time.

In my experience, it's best to side-step the problem altogether.
If you reverse-proxy your request through your rails server, then you can display pretty much anything all the time in your iframe.

Following is an example of the process. I'm assuming that your server is `your-server.com` and the user wants to list a page on `user.com/list`. The way it works would be:

1. Set an iframe's src to https://your-server.com/proxy?url=https://user.com/list`
2. Intercept the request, extract the url: `https://user.com/list`
3. Perform an HTTP request on `https://user.com/list` to fetch the content
4. Return it to the browser as if it come from your own server

This approach works pretty much all the time, but it then has other limitations:
- you should reverse proxy any asset on that page that has a relative url; otherwise the css/images may be broken
- you must handle ajax requests on that page

You can fix these as well, by transforming the html before step 4.
You could use https://github.com/waterlink/rack-reverse-proxy for step 2 and 3, instead of re-implementing your own reverse proxy.

You could set it up using the following code in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.middleware.insert(0, Rack::ReverseProxy) do  
  reverse_proxy_options timeout: 10 # avoids waiting for pages that take forever to load
  reverse_proxy(/proxy\?url=(.*)/, '$1') # reverse proxy on the url parameter
end
```